# Higher order terms in Riemann's formula (normal coordinates)

Tags: riemannian-geometry

In normal coordinates, we have
$$
\Gamma_{ijk}(x)=-\frac{1}{3}(R_{ijkl}(0)+R_{ikjl}(0))x^{l}+O(x^2)
$$
where $ \Gamma_{ijk}\equiv g_{is}\Gamma^s_{jk}$.
My question is whether the higher order terms can be expressed solely in terms of $R_{ijkl}$ and its partial derivatives (evaluated at zero of course).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer would appear to be yes. In fact, the expansion can be derived from the results of this [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/gr-qc/9712092.pdf) which gives a closed form expression for the metric in terms of the curvature in normal coordinates.